# How do I prevent venison (for jerky) from spoiling?

Tags: jerky, venison

I laid out some vension for jerky. It has been in the fridgerator for 2 days. I put it in the marinate today. how long can I leave it so it does not spoil?

Answer (score 3):

stilltasty.com gives you [3-5 days in the fridge](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18637) for fresh, raw venison.